# How to open app inside didDetermineState Method

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

Today I am able to launch a local notification when the mobile gets into the region by using the didDetermineState just like the code bellow, even If the app is not running at all.

```
    if (state == CLRegionState.inside){

        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)


                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Sonda"
                content.subtitle = "Entrada"
                content.body = "Hora: " + String(hour) + ":" + String(minutes)
                content.badge = 1
                content.sound = .default()
                let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 2, repeats: false)
                let requestIdentifier = "reqIdentifier"
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {error in
                    //handle error
                })....
```

Is it possible to launch the app itself within the same method without user interaction?

Thanks in advance,

Filipe

Comment: What do you mean by launch? As in open the app on the screen or perform code?

Comment: I need to open the app to start rangin the beacons and writing some data to the backend..monitoring the activity

Comment: Well it doesn't sound like you have to open the app to start ranging? As long as you have the capability to act with BLE devices in background turned on, you'd be able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no, you cannot launch an iOS to the foreground programmatically.  The design of iOS forbids this, as it always requires a user to gesture to allow an app to cone to the foreground.  The closest you can come is sending a local notification as you have done.  Tapping the local notification is the simplest and most user-friendly way to get that required user gesture.

Comment: What if I want to close de app? It's forbidden as well? I have seen some threads that say you won't be able to update to appstore if you use exit(0)

Comment: The iOS framework is designed so programatically closing apps is unnecessary.  The operating system will close the app when memory is low.  There are some disadvantages of this design, but it isn't worth fighting because there is nothing you can do about it.  Your best bet would be to de-allocate any resources or threads when you are done running your app, and design it so they can be recreated if it is brought back to the foreground by tapping on a launcher icon or a notification.